# Restoring OS to factory image

Tags: lubuntu, backup, restore

Is any built-in tool in Lubuntu (or other Linux from Ubuntu family) allows restore operating system to brand-new snapshot with all default settings?

Comment: No, there is no such feature. But you can re-install that will give the same result.

Comment: Sure, I know, but since I am using Lubuntu uefi and I have to manually set partitions, I felt pain becaise of wastomg time for this proceder. I believed that tjere is wonderful, clear option "reset to factory".If not, I am gonna close this question.

Comment: You don't "have" to manually set pertitions. You've chosen to do it.

Comment: Next time do a backup. Also a good option is to use `btrfs`. You will be able to make snapshots and easily restore the system to any present state. There is also `timeshift` app for that.

Comment: Such tools have been created, at a recycler I volunteered at (CBV) there was a menu item (plus script on the Ubuntu box if they went to terminal) that would reset the machine back to our default - as long as the user didn't format the drive & lose the partition that contained the restoration data. It was added to the boxes, so it can be created.  If they destroyed the system such that it wouldn't boot though; the script couldn't be run & owners would have to *return-to-base* usually.  Our images came with Ubuntu (Unity then GNOME) + MATE included by default and wasn't de/flavor specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an option to Factory Reset, you'll just have to reinstall Lubuntu unfortunately